# My top answerers rating decreased, but overall ratings stayed the same

Tags: bug, top-users

Yesterday, my rating in Top Answerers section for [Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/laravel/topusers) tag was 2106. Also, yesterday I've earned like 30 upvotes, so the rating should be somewhere near 2135.

Instead of that, my rating decreased and now it's 2094. So I've become 5th, but I was 4th yesterday. The rating of the guy who now is 4th and was 5th changed from 2103 to 2106.

My overall SO rating wasn't decreased. I wonder why did this happen to me? I don't see any 'User was removed' or similar messages.

Comment: @approxiblue I don't have any answers with more than 11 upvotes (I don't have any old answers). But I've lost like 42 points.

Comment: My only guess would be that a question/post (or a few) was (or were) deleted where you had 3+ score and the answer was more than 60 days old. That would let you keep the rep, but would remove the score for the tag. But, that is only a guess.

Comment: @Kendra as I said before I don't have any answers with a lot of upvotes, so if it's true, someone has deleted like 10 of my answers at once which doesn't seem right. Is it possible to find out what answers were deleted? Also, I'd really like to know the exact reason, is there any to contact some kind of super moderator regarding this issue and ask for a little investigation?

Comment: SO team answered that there is no way to investigate this issue. They said it could be because someone removed a tag from some of my answers. So some guy could do this again and again and no one can stop this. Not cool.